# How to group by the selected columns\properties of new class in linq?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

```
var query = context.headerItems
            .Where(header => header.headerColumn1 != false)
            .Where(item => item.itemColumn1 != null)
            .Select(header => new {
                //Only columns from header table in here
            })
            .ToList()
            .Select(header => new context.header{
                //Only columns from header table in here
            });
return query.ToList();
```

`headerItems` are join between `header` and `items`.

How do I group by all the selected columns\properties of header?

Comment: Can you show the definition of `context.headerItems`?

Comment: Possible duplicate with : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq

Comment: @Rafalon `context.headerItems` consist all columns from `header` and some columns from `items`.

Comment: @Pop yeah cool, but I don't know what is `header` and what is `items` and what is *some columns*. Please understand that people **can't see your screen**. Also note that you are using `.ToList()` twice

Answer (score 1):

If you want to group all columns and don't need to calculate count or total, you can simply use `distinct` that would also give the same result.